# Fetch next date from based on a date parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to fetch back the next date based on a date I already know. I am using the following query but this returns all dates and all nextdates for the entire recordset. I can understand that I am asking for dates greater than my search date, but if I use `WHERE = '2010-01-01 04:30:00.000'` then I get no results. How can I fetch only the next date?

The query is (using SQL Server 2012 Express):

```
SELECT [DateTime], [Item], LEAD([DateTime]) OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime]) NextDate
FROM cteList
WHERE [DateTime] > '2010-01-01 04:30:00.000'
ORDER BY [DateTime];
```

Comment: Top 1..........

Comment: Have you tried adding `TOP 1` to your `SELECT`? Ex. `SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime]...`

Comment: please tell us whats your desire output

Comment: Doh! So obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated you can limit your existing query `TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime], [Item], LEAD([DateTime]) OVER (ORDER BY [DateTime]) NextDate
FROM cteList
WHERE [DateTime] > '2010-01-01 04:30:00.000'
ORDER BY [DateTime];
```

For you to use `WHERE [DateTime] =` you would have to have the exact datetime to the corresponding row in your table.